# ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric' [Google Colab, Titanic]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

Im trying to do some machine learning. The error appears on line 14. Any help is hugely appreciated.

```
# Data to be predicted
X_to_be_predicted = my_df[my_df.Survived.isnull()]
X_to_be_predicted = X_to_be_predicted.drop(['Survived'], axis = 1)
# X_to_be_predicted[X_to_be_predicted.Age.isnull()]
# X_to_be_predicted.dropna(inplace = True) # 417 x 27
#Training data
train_data = my_df
train_data = train_data.dropna()
feature_train = train_data['Survived']
label_train = train_data.drop(['Survived'], axis = 1)
##Gaussian
clf = GaussianNB()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(label_train, feature_train, test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(x_train, np.ravel(y_train))
print("NB Accuracy: " + repr(round(clf.score(x_test, y_test) * 100, 2)) + "%")
result_rf = cross_val_score(clf, x_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring = 'accuracy')
print('The cross validated score for Random forest is:', round(result_rf.mean()*100,2))
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf,x_train, y_train, cv=10)
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred), annot=True, fmt = '3.0f', cmap = "summer")
plt.title('Confusion_matrix for NB', y=1.05, size=15)
```

Please what does this mean? I have been trying to deploy my model but this keeps coming up when I run it

Comment: `fit` works with numbers.  `x_train` (or `y_train`) contains strings, strings that can't be turned into numbers.  This is **your** data, we can't examine it, that's your job!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the error you are getting. I think you are getting the error in this line
clf.fit(x_train, np.ravel(y_train))

Try this : clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

Because you are already gave the inputs to x_train and y_train. Now your task is to fit the train data.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please, format you answer separating the code from the description